# vimeo video embedded in the site does not work in Windows 8 (except in quirks mode)

Tags: html, windows-8, vimeo, internet-explorer-10

Our institutional web site (wordpress instance) has some vimeo embedded videos in the homepage that do not work in windows 8 IE10, unless quirks mode is enabled.

Not sure what is wrong with this:

```
     <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/51800426?badge=0&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" width="896" height="504" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

I don't want to force quirks mode on the site, if possible.

Thanks in advance for any tip...

Comment: Also, if I refresh the page in document standard mode (with a Ctrl-F5), then the video shows up... :|

Comment: Does replacing the three instances of `&` with `&amp;` make a difference?

Comment: what's the source site?  The iframe put into a <!DOCTYPE html> document (standards mode) seems to work for me both in the Modern UI and desktop.

Comment: Jim, the site is www.heapsylon.com.
It's a wordpress site, and the doctype is different.
I'll try to see if I can force the doctype differently

Comment: tried to replace the doctype but the behavior is the same... :S

Comment: Jim, I tried to do the same as you mention above, and can't see what you see. Please try www.heapsylon.com/test.html. It's a barebone page, and it has the same behavior for me: empty page first time, video shown upon refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's officially a Vimeo issue.
https://vimeo.com/forums/help/topic:92711